# Grails replace object in one-to-one association

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have two following domains:

```
User {
   UserData userData
}

UserData {
   static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

and at some point I want to merge two users into one. I mean delete one instance of User and attache userData to another user.

I've tried:

```
User zombieUser
User liveUser

UserData data = zombieUser.userData
zombieUser.delete()
liveUser.userData = data
userData.user = liveUser
userData.save()
liveUser.save()
```

Actually I've tried different variants, different order, seems that all possible ways. But it always fails with an exceptions. Current code will fail with:

```
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [UserData#1]
```

If i've put `zombie.delete()` to bottom, after `*.save()`, I will get:

```
Field error in object 'User' on field 'userData': rejected value [UserData : 1]; codes ... default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] must be unique]
```

Are there any way to reconnect existing object from one object to another?

---

Working code:

```
UserData userData = zombieUser.userData

userData.user = null
zombieUser.userData = null
zombieUser.save(flush: true)
userData.save()

liveUser.userData = userData
userData.user = liveUser
liveUser.save()
userDate.save(flush: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that because of your `belongsTo` declaration, and according to [cascading rules](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html), `userData` is deleted from the database as soon as `zombieUser` is deleted. When `liveUser.save()` is called, `userData` would be saved again. By the way, you call to `userData.save()` is not needed as again, because of this `belongsTo` declaration, `liveUser.save()` is cascaded to `userData`.

I see **two options** for solving your problem:

1. Perform a **deep copy of `userData` to a new `UserData`** object, and attach this object to `liveUser`, like this:

   ```
   withTransaction {
     UserData data = new UserData(prop: zombieUser.userData.prop)
     liveUser.userData = data
     zombiUser.delete()
     liveUser.save()
   }
   ```

   The old UserData object will be deleted by cascade when deleting `zombieUser` and a new one will be created when saving `liveUser`.
2. **Remove `belongsTo` from `userData`.** You won't benefit of cascading anymore, and will have to manage saving `userData` yourself, and make sure `user.userData` is deleted from the database when no `user` reference it (don't forget to make transactions for that, as always when you have several call to `save` or `delete` in your method).

Which approach you choose depends on how coupled your objects are. Typically, if they are very coupled, you will benefit of cascading (through `belongsTo`) and may go for 1. If they are not very coupled, (i.e. there may be several users with the same userData), then `belongsTo` is wrong and you should choose approach 2.

The concepts presented in [GORM gotchas](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/) will greatly help you if you have a GORM model with complicated dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! After your answer i've found third option: set `userData.user` and `zombie.userData` to `null` before deletion of zombie user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a mapping to your domain class to tell it what to do when you delete an object. For example, should deleting a parent also delete all its children??

```
static mapping = {
    userData cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
}
```

Comment: hm, but what if don't need deletion of child object (UserData) ? only parent (User). And attach existing child to another parent. Is it possible?